# Notepad++ delete everything outside the " quotes with regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

I searched and try so much until now, but I think it is better to ask.

Situation:

I have a file with multiple lines (around 5000) like this:

*Testtext und hier steht noch mehr!

Franz jagt in einem total verwahrlosten Taxi durch die Eifel

Hier ist eine Zeile mit einer Information, die Information ist "ABC12345"

Zu der Information gibt es eine 2te Zeile mit einer weiteren Information "Info1|Info2|Info3"

Dann kommt noch eine ueberfluessige Zeile*

... and I just need the informations `ABC12345` and `Info1|Info2|Info3`.

I want to delete everything else what is not between the quotes.
Every information block is in the same way.

And I also want to delete the lines without important information's

That I get:
ABC12345
Info1|Info2|Info3
ZYX9876
Info9|Info7|Info5

or the same with quotes (that's not important)

I tried to search the Regex `\"(.*?)\"` that's fine, I can find everything inside the "quotes".

After that my next step was to say delete everything was is NOT `\"(.*?)\"`
... over search and replace.

But I do not understand how I can negate this.

`(?!(\"(.*?)\"))` doesn't work.

I think for a specialist it is so easy to solve it, please help me.

Comment: OK, I can now delete everthing what i didn't need in the line with the information with this regEx: .*(\"(.*?)\").* 
But the Lines without the Informations in the quotes are still there!
I use \1 or $1 in the replace field!

Comment: Try Find `"(.+?)"|.\n?`  and replace all:`$1`

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `".+?"(*SKIP)(*F)|.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
".+?"           # matches something beween quotes
(*SKIP)(*F)     # fail the match
|               # OR
.               # any  character
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Hello, THX 4 that. This is nearly what I need. If I use this I habe to delete the empty rows, that's possible with notepad++.
I tried some other things with the original files (a little bit other Text) and I can also delete the lines without important Information.

Find:  .*(\"(.*?)\").*|.*Job.*[\r]?[\n]||.*job.*[\r]?[\n]
Restore: 1

Job and job is in the lines I didn't need. So I have as result only 2X times the 2 lines with the Information.

BUT THANKS all this infos from you help to find the  final solution! Thump up!

Comment: @duckknight: That is not what you've asked. You should update the question or, better, ask a new one with **real** text and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in this case with the "more" original files:

> Some Text with the word Job
>  Some other with job
>  Job has been
> sent to "ABC1234"
>  Job owner's username "Info1|Info2"

```
Find: .*(\"(.*?)\").*|.*Job.*[\r]?[\n]||.*job.*[\r]?[\n]
Restore: $1
```

Job and job is also Text in the lines I didn't need. So I have as a result only X times the 2 lines with the Information and no empty rows.

Thanks to all this info from you that helped to find the final solution!

Comment: That is not what you've asked. You should update the question or, better, ask a new one with **real** text and expected result.

Comment: @duckknight,  Share a small portion of your data if possible,  and also the changes that you want as a sample texr  to understand you better,  you will get a your desired code that you were looking for...

Comment: Hello Toto, Sorry, but this was EXACT MY QUESTION, only the Text wasn't correct. With .*(\"(.*?)\").*|.*Job.*[\r]?[\n]||.*job.*[\r]?[\n] I can delete EVERYTHING what is not between the quotas! 

@Haji Rahmatullah  I think you understand, that I can not post original userdata and system data but the text is nearly the same as I wrote in my own answer. 
AND: It is solved with the syntax. I catch your information and change it to my needs. That in the answer from me.
There is nothing more to do! I answer myself, so other users can pick up the syntax if they need it

Thanks!!